# Create FY based on the range of date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, date-range

I am working on dates and FY.
My working data set contains ten thousands of rows with date.
I want to create a new column to identify the season or FY.
The sample data frame is as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = ['10/08/2018','12/09/2018','15/08/2017','16/05/2018']
```

what I wanted to do is to create a new column **season** based on the range of the date.
for example,
if the month of the date is from AUgust to June, it will be considered as a season.
It means that the date ranges from 01/08/2005 to 30/06/2006, the season will be 2005-06.

For the sample date frame, the expected output will be as follow:

```
  date      season
10/082018   2018-19
12/09/2018  2018-19
15/08/2017  2017-18
16/05/2018  2017-18
```

Below is my expected output:

[image]

How would I define the range and the season??
Thanks,

Zep.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Images are difficult to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the condition based on month and concatenate the year part of the date after converting to string

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format = '%d/%m/%Y')
cond = df.date.dt.month >=8
df['season'] = np.where(cond, df.date.dt.year.apply(str) + '-' + (df.date.dt.year+1).apply(str).str[2:], (df.date.dt.year-1).apply(str) + '-' + df.date.dt.year.apply(str).str[2:])


    date    season
0   2018-08-10  2018-19
1   2018-09-12  2018-19
2   2017-08-15  2017-18
3   2018-05-16  2017-18
```

Comment: Thanks Vaishali. I converted the Date to datetime and got with the following format.
time data Timestamp('2018-08-10 00:00:00')
how can I remove the time part from date time?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Zephyr, df['date'].dt.date will give you the date component of datetime

Comment: @Vaishali I would suggest to use `year = df.date.dt.year;year_str = df.date.dt.year.astype(str);np.where(cond,year_str + '-' + (year+1).astype(str).str[2:], (year-1).astype(str) + '-' + year_str.str[2:])` to speed up the process since you have lot of intermediate same variables.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa, may be you compared the time for the given number of rows. Try it on df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True) and times are identical.

Comment: @Vaishali Oh that's interesting and thank you for letting me know that.